# dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm incrementing by half hour in vba

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have got a start date and end date in this custom format
**dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm** in excel cells.
What i need is to fill specific row with dates incremented by half hour from start date to end date using VBA code. And i havent got any idea how to do this.

On web there are some examples with similar problems but with only months or only hours and those are dates format not custom.

Comment: The format of the date shouldn't matter if you use the correct function.  You should be able to use the DATEADD function here, I believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a simple formula.

1. Write your start date into cell A1
2. In A2 write `=A1+(1/48)`
3. Copy formula from A2 down

done.

**How does this work?**
Excel dates are represented as count of days since `1900`. That means `1900-01-01` is the first day and represented by `1`. All other dates are just the count of days since then. `1` represents one day. So since 1 day has 24 hours `1/48` represents half an hour.

The number format `dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm` how Excel shows the date is not relevant, because Excel only saves the value (amount of days since `1900`) in the cell value.
So if you type the date of today into a cell `2018-10-11` Excel actually saves `43384` in the cell value (today it is 43384ᵗʰ day since `1900-01-01`).

Answer (score 0):

One option is to find the interval between start and stop point.  Remember that excel dates that are actually dates and not strings are actually integers.  The second thing to remember is time is the decimal part which represent fraction of a day.  Test if your date (assuming it's in A1) is an actual date or a string with

```
=ISNUMBER(A1)
```

If that comes back `TRUE` you do not need to worry about converting your date.  If it comes back `FALSE`, its actually a string and will need to be converted for excel to work with it.

Divide this interval by 30 minutes, or 30/60/24 to and add 1.  This will tell you how many iteration you will need which you can put into a For loop

```
Start_Number = Range("A1")
End_number = Range(("A2")

Stamp = Start_Number
Interval_number = End_Number - Start_Number
Counter = integer of (Interval_number / (30/60/24))

For x = 1 to counter
   write Stamp to cell
   Stamp = Stamp + 30/60/24
Next x
```

Allternatively you could set up a while loop.

```
Do While datetime < Stop_Point
    Write datetime to cell
    Datetime=datetime + 30/60/24
Loop
```

Please note, not actual code but giving idea where OP had no idea where to start.